# Bluegiga BLE112 data transfer from Windows PC to ios devices

Tags: ios, .net, bluetooth, gatt, bluegiga

Is it possible to do a data transfer(less than 1mb data) from a windows pc to ios devices?

I am looking for a solution to transfer data from a windows machine to ios devices via bluetooth LE and found bluegiga BLE112 is a good option but I am not sure whether  can transfer data which is not GATT profile can send from a .net application to an ios application.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but the BLE protocol is not well suited for sending large amounts of data over Bluetooth. If you do want to do it, Bluegiga has an [example project in their forum.](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/29185293--BGScript-spp-over-ble-AT-command-SPP-implementation-for-BLE)

From their post:

> The Bluegiga SPP-over-BLE profile and projects are built to provide
>   the simplest possible method to connect two of our modules together so
>   that you can send arbitrary data back and forth, much like using SPP
>   with a classic Bluetooth device. The BLE protocol is not built to
>   allow this kind of data transfer in a very efficient way, due to the
>   very small packet payload size (20 bytes max) and the relatively large
>   delays required between packets (the BLE radio can only be on for less
>   than 25% of the time even in the most aggressive transmit
>   configuration). However, it is possible using normal Bluetooth Smart
>   GATT operations to appear as though you have an open, transparent data
>   pipe between each end of the connection.

Also, they note that the maximum throughput is ~1 Kbyte/sec. So it may not be practical for the sizes you're wanting to send.

Answer (score 3):

Having done a fair amount of BLE work with Android, iOS, and Windows development, I'll say that transferring large amounts of data is a pain.

The real limitations come from the iOS side actually, because they internally limit the transfer latencies (this has improved from iOS 6 to iOS 7, and I haven't tested throughput on iOS 8 yet).

Bluegiga has some old performance testing data here: https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/22400867--HOW-TO-Maximize-throughput-with-BLE-modules

My personal testing (BLE112 and iOS 6 or 7) showed about 1000 bytes/s using acknowledged data transfer, and 4000 bytes/second with unacknowledged data transfer. I don't think this was an optimal testing condition, but it gives a good ballpark.

From Bluegiga (ideal conditions):

> The best we have seen between two of our BLE modules is about 60Kbps
>   (unacknowledged packets).

The future of BLE looks good, as BT 4.2 is pushing a bit on the throughput (via increasing packet sizes): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v4.2

Unfortunately, the silicon for that probably won't come out until later this year, and who knows when it'll be supported by iOS (and Android).